# Mapbox/MapLibre how to save the latest location.hash updates

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

While the camera is moving around the map, the hash that is in the URL is updated, I need to save this value so that when I return to the map I will be in the same place as before I left

I used this code, the latest changes are saved in sessionStorage, but when switching to another address of my application and returning, sessionStorage was updated to the initial value, and did not accept the necessary past saves

```
    function initLocationHash () {
        let newHash = window.location.hash
        sessionStorage.setItem('locationHash', JSON.stringify(newHash))
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let storedHash = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('locationHash'));

        if (storedHash) {
            window.location.hash = storedHash
        }
        console.log(storedHash, 'storedHash')
    })

    setInterval(function () {
        let storedHash = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('locationHash'));
        let currentHash = window.location.hash
        if (currentHash !== storedHash) {

            initLocationHash()
        }
    }, 100)
```

Comment: Hi Pavel and welcome here :) Not the solution you are looking for, but I suggest you to replace you `setInterval` loop by a `window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {...});`

Comment: @Philippe yea, I was try it, but nothing changes. I think Map class have some events which will help me with solution